# what is this response format image

Tags: android, binary-image

i am trying to create an app which removes the image background, the send the image through api key and server sends the response, here i get response but i coulnt understand the response image format. PLEASE senior developer and programmers help me.
sample response code  : : ‰PNG

������IHDR����˜����������,ƒ7ª����
{{{;Ž}ƒ#âtp¶8_<Nˆ+ÄUàZp'pWp¸¼ÞïŒÅóðËñeøF|?ŽŸ!(Œ ®„HB*a-¡’ÐF8K¸KxA$õˆNÄp¢€¸†XI<D<O%¾%QHf$6)$!m!í'"Ý"½ “ÉFdr<YLÞBn&Ÿ!ß'¿Q *X*(ðV+Ô(t*\Qx¦ˆW4TôT\¬˜¯X¡xDqHñ©^ÉH‰-ÄQZ¥T£tTé†Ò´2UÙF9T9Cy³r‹òåG,ÅˆâCáQŠ(û(g(cT„ªOeS¹ÔuÔFêYê8C3¦ÐRi¥´ohƒ´)ŠŠJ´JžJÊq)¡Ñèéô2úaúuú;U-UOU¾ê&Õ6Õ+ª¯Õæ¨y¨ñÕJÔÚÕFÔÞ©3Ô}ÔÓÔ·©w©ßÓ@i˜i„käjìÑ8«ñtmŽËîœ’9‡çÜÖ„5Í4#4WhîÓÐœÖÒÖòÓÊÒªÒ:£õT›®í¡ª½Cû„ö¤UÇMG ³Cç¤Îc†
5eCÙ‹²»Å4ÙÏÔ€ÄD²^2šã–S“ó&7:÷Hžrž0o`¹ÙòMË'ò}ó¿^ZÁ]Ñ[ [°¶`t¥çÊúUÐª¥«zWë¯.Z=¾ÆoÍµ„µik(´.,/|¹.f]O‘VÑš¢±õ~ë[‹ŠEÅ76¸l¨ÛˆÚ(Ø8¸iî¦ªMKx%K-K+Jßoæn¾ø•ÍW•_}Ú’´e°Ì¡lÏVÌVáÖëÛÜ·(W.Ï/Û²½scGÉŽ—;—ì¼PaWQ·‹°K²KZ\Ù]ePµµê}uJõHWM{-fí¦Ú×»y»¯ìñØÓV§UWZ÷n¯`ïÍz¿úÎ£†Š}˜}9û6F7öÍúº¹I£©´éÃ~á~éˆ}ÍŽÍÍ-š-e¬p«¤uò`ÂÁËßxÓÝÆl«o§·—‡$‡›øíõÃA‡{°Ž´}gø]mµ£¤ê\Þ9Õ•Ò%íŽë>x´·Ç¥§ã{Ëï÷Ó=Vs\åxÙ Â‰¢ŸNæŸœ>•uêééäÓc½Kzïœ‰=s-/¼oðlÐÙóç|Ïé÷ì?yÞõü±ÎŽ^d]ìºäp©sÀ~ ãû:;‡‡º/;]îž7|âŠû•ÓW½¯ž»píÒÈü‘áëQ×oÞH¸!½É»ùèVú¬ç·snÏÜYs}·äžÒ½Šûš÷~4ý±]ê =>ê=:ð`Áƒ;cÜ±'?eÿô~¼è!ùaÅ„ÎDó#ÛGÇ&}'/?^øxüIÖ“™§Å?+ÿ\ûÌäÙw¿xü20;5þ\ôüÓ¯›_¨¿ØÿÒîeïtØôýW¯f^—¼Qsà-ëmÿ»˜w3¹ï±ï+?˜~èùôñî§ŒOŸ~÷„óû¤Ì\9������ pHYs����������šœ������IDATx^ìýœ¤éUÞŸÊ

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is PNG as it starts with `‰PNG..`

Comment: How to convert this PNG into bitmap ?please provide me some block of code.

Comment: well, you can simply open the file and convert it to any image editor. If you want to covert it programmatically finds the library or SDK that your programming language support, for example: https://datatofish.com/png-to-jpg-python/